# Test the last value dyplr::mutated for calculating the current value

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to mutate a new column in mtcars, but make the new entry (row) dependent in on the just-previous row in the same column (the example using mtcars is admittedly nonsense).

Simplify mtcars with...

```
m.subset <- mtcars[2:7, 10:11]  # top few rows and only the relevant columns
```

Similar questions have been asked...

[Reuse value of previous row during dplyr::mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56638199/reuse-value-of-previous-row-during-dplyrmutate)

[use the diff function with mutate at from dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66485682/use-the-diff-function-with-mutate-at-from-dplyr)

...and others, but all seem to refer to existing columns, not the subject one -- or they refer to multiple columns/rows as they currently exist.

For example, neither of the following work:

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% # doesn't work
  mutate (
    newcol = gear + carb + 
      ifelse(shift(newcol, n=1, type = "lag") >4, 0, 1)
  )

mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% # doesn't work
  mutate (
    newcol = gear + carb + 
      ifelse(shift(., n=1, type = "lag") >4, 0, 1)
  )
```

...and while the following works, it's wrong:

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>% # works but wrong
  mutate (
    newcol = gear + carb + 
      ifelse(lag(.) >4, 0, 1)
  )
```

Result I am looking for is:

[image]

Comment: why can't a temp column be created with `gear + carb

Comment: `(lag(gear + carb) <= 4) + gear + carb` ?

Comment: You could wrap with `{}` and use `m.subset %>% mutate(newcol = {tmp <- gear + carb; tmp + ifelse(lag(tmp) > 4, 0, 1)})`

Comment: Or may also use `library(pipeR);m.subset %>>% (~tmp = .$gear + .$carb) %>% mutate(newcol = tmp + ifelse(lag(tmp) > 4, 0, 1))`

Comment: @akrun, thanks for your very helpful comments; I read up on both the use of `{}` and `pipeR`.  I'm sure I'll use these at some point.

Comment: @akrun, I just asked a follow up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72147545/dplyr-lags-on-summarised-grouped-data.  The new question deals with grouped data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option doing it in two steps:

```
library(dplyr)

m.subset %>%
  mutate(newcol = ifelse(gear + carb <= 4, TRUE, FALSE),
         newcol = gear + carb + lag(newcol))
```

**Output**

```
                  gear carb temp
Mazda RX4 Wag        4    4   NA
Datsun 710           4    1    5
Hornet 4 Drive       3    1    4
Hornet Sportabout    3    2    6
Valiant              3    1    4
Duster 360           3    4    8
```

Comment: #AndrewGB; thanks.  Question, though: I don't see where "temp" is defined.  Did you mean to define temp in the first part of the mutate?

Comment: @WBarker You’re right. It should have been newcol. I updated to match the name of your output and forgot to change that part. I’ve corrected it now.

Comment: just accepted your answer; it's taken me this long to incorporate your suggestion into the real problem (sometimes perhaps reprex's can be TOO simple!)